# Using value from text box to a variable on a button formaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am trying to work on a button in one of my pages and my syntax is messed up using the formaction method/attribute.  I wanted to have the ‘senddate’ parameter in the servlet routing be based on a value in a text box.  I check the text box and I am getting a value.  I even tried doing some alerts on a mousedown function to make sure that $('#txtProcessedDate').val() is valid and got the date.  But it isn’t working in the servlet as it shows '$('.   What is the best way to use the txtProcessedDate text box value in this formaction statement?

```
  <button style="margin-left:20%; font-weight:bold" id="updatePayment" 
            type="submit" 
            formaction="EFTscreen?action=routeEFTC&senddate=$('#txtProcessedDate').val() "
            class="btn btn-success bold">Update Payment Status
  </button>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not the right way to concatenate the value to the text of the attribute value. You can do it like so:

`$("#updatePayment").attr({"formaction": $("#updatePayment").attr("formaction")+"&senddate="+$("#txtProcessedDate").val()});`

Comment: Is that first statement a combination of the second because it looks like it is missing something?   Is this supposed to be two statements or one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have javascript in formaction attribute, try to add keyup event where you change it:

```
$('#txtProcessedDate').keyup(function() {
    var url = "EFTscreen?action=routeEFTC&senddate=";
    $("#updatePayment").attr("formaction",  url + $(this).val());
});
```